# Do we need reason for "Not Doing" something?

Tags: logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a negative claimant have a burden of proof?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/678/does-a-negative-claimant-have-a-burden-of-proof)

I have always wondered if `NOT doing something` requires reason like `doing something` does.
As an example, do you think the following Q/A is rational?

> -Do you believe in God? 
> -No 
> -Why? 
> -It's `believing in God` that requires reason! `Not believing` does not need reason!

Comment: Your question is interesting but is a duplicate of another.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, there is more of a burden to supply a reason for doing (or believing) something than not doing (or believing) something, but this is not always the case; for example, it is generally accepted that I would need a very good reason for *not* believing that the cup I see in front of me is actually there.

Answer (score 2):

In any given context, we may or may not "need" justification for any particular belief or statement; this relates to the notion of **[burden of proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophic_burden_of_proof)**. While typically the **burden of proof** is on the person asserting a claim, it doesn't always have to be a *positive* assertion. I.E., it's not always merely when someone is asserting the existence of something *new*, but can also apply when someone is denying the existence of something other people take to be an obvious truth. On a basic level, it might be more appropriate to view the burden of proof as lying with the person who makes claims which are not self-evident, as opposed to merely "non-negating".